# Getting an empty query set Django

Tags: django, search, django-queryset

I'm trying to develop a search functionality but only getting a empty query set every single time .

```
class SearchView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "search.html"

    def get_context(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context(**kwargs)
        kw = self.request.GET.get("search")
        results = Thread.objects.filter(Q(heading__icontains=kw) | Q(thread_content__icontains=kw))
        print(results)
        
        context["results"] = results
        return context
```

Template

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}Search{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div class = "container">
    <div class = "row">
        <div class = "col-md-12">
            <h3>Search results for <span class="text-info">"{{ request.GET.search }}"</span></h3>
            <h3>{{results}}</h3>
            <hr>
            {% for item in results %}
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <img src = "{{item.image.url}}" class="img-fluid" alt = "">
               
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <h4>{{item.heading}}</h4>
                <p>{{item.thread_content}}</p>

            </div>
            {%endfor%}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

request.GET.search is returning correctly , but the rest is not getting displayed

Comment: is it displaying results?

Comment: There might be no data in the table that contains words you are trying to search. You are printing results as output so check your console for output as well, perhaps you can see results there

Comment: Weirdly the same code started working after some time . The print statements that were not working in console also started printing after some time . My Debug is ON  I don't know why is there a delay in my response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a real strange issue. The Browser cache took a long time to refresh with my updated code. Once I cleared the Browser Cache and Settings, it started working again.